# SQL Server or C# transpose

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I know this seems like a very basic question but it isn't; I can't use SQL Server pivot because I don't want SUM, I just want to transpose.

How can I transpose SQL data either in SQL query on in C# LINQ?  Which is the fastest?

**General data**

```
| Company | Product | Count |
|---------|---------|-------|
|   Cloud |   Nokia |    10 |
|   Cloud | Samsung |    30 |
|   Cloud |    Sony |    42 |
|    Coms |   Apple |    34 |
|    Coms |   Nokia |    39 |
|    Coms | Samsung |    11 |
|    Coms |    Sony |    22 |
|      RP |   Nokia |    22 |
|      RP | Samsung |    29 |
|      RP |    Sony |    22 |
```

Into this:

```
| Company | Nokia | Samsung | Sony |  Apple |
|---------|-------|---------|------|--------|
|   Cloud |    10 |      30 |   42 |      0 |
|    Coms |    39 |      11 |   22 |     34 |
|      RP |    22 |      29 |   22 |      0 |
```

Comment: You can still use `SUM()` (or `MAX()`, `MIN()`, etc.) because technically they would only be acting upon a single value.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT 
    Company
    , [Nokia]
    , [Samsung]
    , [Sony]
    , [Apple]
FROM
    YourTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(Count) FOR Product IN ([Nokia], [Samsung], [Sony], [Apple])
)
AS p
```

Will produce:

```
| COMPANY | NOKIA | SAMSUNG | SONY |  APPLE |
|---------|-------|---------|------|--------|
|   Cloud |    10 |      30 |   42 | (null) |
|    Coms |    39 |      11 |   22 |     34 |
|      RP |    22 |      29 |   22 | (null) |
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10ffc2/7)

Comment: Thank you very much also how can I get Sum of each row - Example Cloud : Nokia+Samsung+sony+apple=82